# Add crosshair to embedded chart

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to update one of my Google Spreadsheet embedded chart with crosshairs. After reading the doc, I've come to the conclusion that this code should work :

```
function ChartLine()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("someId").getSheetByName("someSheet");
  var chartBuilder = sheet.getCharts()[0].modify().asLineChart();
  chartBuilder.setOption("crosshair", { trigger: 'both' });
  sheet.updateChart(chartBuilder.build());
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not add crosshairs. I've been able to modify the chart's title using similar code. So, I'm left wondering why it is not working.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Crosshair Documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/crosshairs) you can use this small snippet below to try and see if it works for you:

```
function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number');
        data.addColumn('number');
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
          data.addRow([Math.floor(Math.random()*100),
                       Math.floor(Math.random()*100)]);
        var options = {
          legend: 'none',
          crosshair: { trigger: 'both' } // Display crosshairs on focus and selection.
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

Play with it until you get the necessary results you need.